# Multiple Virtual Machines Windows 10 vs Windows Server With Multiple Users?

Tags: windows

I have a few different type of windows software for my work. They are all independent of one another. I have a powerful HP server for this.

If I have let's say 5 different software, what would be better resource-wise:
1. Install each software on separate windows 10 virtual machine
2. Install one windows server and install all 5 software on it and access them through separate users?

I suppose the server would use less resources as it is one OS versus 5 OSes, but how big of a difference would be between both solutions?

(Assume all 5 software work simultaneously)

Comment: Assuming that all five pieces of software can co-exist and utilize / require the exact same resources, I would absolutely recommend you to set up just the one server for hosting them, both to conserve resources used for systems (I'm assuming they will be running through Hyper-V or similar), but also for simplicity when it comes to patch management and maintaining the hosted environment in generel.

Comment: *how big of a difference* depends on too many variables to be answered definitely, which makes that part of your question off-topic on Server Fault. Otherwise you're correct that a single OS installation vs. five is more efficient... *usually*, depending...on factors like how well the five software packages play with each other and other variables.